# Filter Array of Objects by its [[Double]] Property?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, filtering

I have an array (`features`) that contains `Feature` objects.

The `Feature` has a property called `coordinates`

`feature.coordinates` in a nested array of latitude/longitude double values, `[[Double]]` — they make a polygon.

Given min/max latitude values, say -44.5 and -40.5 I want to filter the features array to just the features that have at least one latitude value in its coordinates array in that range.

I'm struggling to do it with `flatMap` and `filter` because it's so heavily nested. Do I need to change my data structure? I'm looking for high performance.

Comment: Can't you just add a method on your `Feature` object that computes your predicate, and then filter on your array of features?

Comment: Storing long/lat as `[[Double]]` makes this whole problem a lot harder than it needs to be. At the highest level, use `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]`. If you don't want CoreLocation, create a `Location` struct and make it `[Location]`. If you don't want to create a type, use `[(Double, Double)]`. All of those will be much simpler (and potentially much faster) to handle these kinds of things. Going further, I would probably abstract the whole thing to `Region` (or use `CLRegion`), so you can easily implement `contains(point:)`, and then this is trivial.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this data is fetched from Core Data.

Comment: As an aside, rather than store coordinates in Core Data as `Double` pairs, you can use a **transient** attribute, set the **Custom Class** to `CLLocation`, and the module to **CoreLocation**